# Why is the past tense of text, as used by some people, pronounced "text-ted" and not just "tested"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, pronunciation, dialects

Why is the past tense of text, as used by some people, pronounced text-Ted and not just tested? One wouldn't say risk-ked for risked, or ask-ked for asked?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misspelled texted.my phone accepted tested instead.

Comment: I think the common pronunciation is "tex-ted", not "text-ted". The "x" has a "ks" sound, and there's only one "t" sound in the middle of the word, not two. How does the "xt" portion of the first syllable of your "text-Ted" pronunciation sound like?

Comment: I think the common pronunciation is "text-ID" (i.e. - unavoidably there must be two syllables, but the second one is invariably a short 'i', and it *doesn't* include (or repeat) the consonant 't').  I would like to know why this question title here includes the word ***cajun***, which in context means nothing whatsoever to me.

Answer (score 2):

The final *t* in *text* makes all the difference. In *risk* and *ask*, you are ending on a final *s* followed by a *k* sound, so you are able to add the *d* without trouble. But in *text*, you don't have *s* followed by *k*—you have *k* followed by *s* followed by *t*. Not only are the *s* and *k* sounds swapped, but you have an extra dental sound to finish the word. There is no clean way to transition from *kst* to a *d* sound the way that you can in the word *ask*.

There is a way to distinguish *ask* from *asked* (when hearing the words). There is no way to clearly distinguish *text* from *textd*—especially in American English where the *t* and *d* sounds at the ends of words are not always distinguishable.

It's also worth noting that using *text* as a verb is a recent construction, so the etymology of the past tense of the verb *text* would be based on what "sounds good" to modern speakers rather than what "sounded good" in the past when *ask* and *risk* were first used in the past tense. In other words, when dealing with new construction, one can't always rely upon how it used to be done as evidence of how it will be done in the future.

Comment: The word *text* already sounds past-tense like (in the way that flexed and perplexed are), so the conscious addition of "ed" solves this, but with some risk of sounding redundant or in error (like a young child saying "bestest" or "thinked"). However it doesn't seem to be particularly remarkable, and is not dissimilar to other slightly awkward past tense forms, such as pasted, misted, rested, dusted, boosted, and hoisted.

Comment: It could have been the case that *text* emerged / evolved as both the present and past tense form (as with "hit"), but clearly it didn't sit comfortably enough with a majority of users, Perhaps it could have been *taxt*.

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with the "xt" in text being a 3-consonant cluster since in English,the letter x is pronounced "ks". Thus another phonetic spelling would be "teksted". The difference in pronunciation seems to be because the syllables can be divided as either "tek-sted" or "teks-ted".

The "sk" in asked and risked is only a 2-consonant cluster; therefore, the division between syllables can only occur one way.